# Emgu CV undistort image gives blank result sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, matrix, emgucv

Im undistorting an image using intrinsic values of camera martix and distortion coeeficient. It corrects the distortion perfectly. But if I load same image twice, sometimes it gives out a blank gray image. Not sure why this is happening.

```
 void distort()
    {

            Mat cameraMatrix = new Mat(3, 3, DepthType.Cv64F,1);

            Mat distCoeffs = new Mat(8, 1, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);

            //Camera matrix values
            double fx = 5715.63;
            double fy = 5788.09;
            double cx = 1339.66;
            double cy = 941.89;
            //double skew = 0.11273;

            //Optical distortion coefficient values
            double k1 = -2.006166;
            double k2 = 5.478401;
            //double k3 = 0.001513;
            double p1 = 0.007517;
            double p2 = -0.007439;

            //Set the camera matrix
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(0, 0, fx);
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(1, 1, fy);
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(1, 0, 1);
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(0, 2, cx);
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(1, 2, cy);
            cameraMatrix.SetValue(2, 2, 1);

            //Set the distortion matrix
            distCoeffs.SetValue(0, 0, k1);
            distCoeffs.SetValue(1, 0, k2);
            distCoeffs.SetValue(2, 0, p1);
            distCoeffs.SetValue(3, 0, p2);

            //Read the input image

            image = CvInvoke.Imread(@"33.bmp", ImreadModes.Color);

            Correct the input image
            Mat outFrame = image.Clone();
            CvInvoke.Undistort(image, outFrame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

            //save the corrected image
            image = outFrame.Clone();
            imageBox1.Image = image.Bitmap;

            image.Dispose();
            outFrame.Dispose();


    }
```

Comment: Where are you loading the image from?  If it is reading the image incorrectly randomly there are usually two reasons 1) The disk may contains errors.So you may want to run a check of the disk to fix errors.Often a dish that has been read/write a lot of times may contain errors.Solid state disks have a much shorter life span the convention hard disks 2) You are not reading the entire file before trying to display the file.Again if a solid state disk is been read/written a lot of times the access time increases.If you have any timers in your application the access times may need to be increased.

Comment: hi, i have a regular HDD. Also tried capturing an image from camera. Same thing happens. Sometimes it shows correct image, sometimes its just blank gray image.